# Ionic ElementRef access the native element

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have written a directive to automatically change height of an ion-textarea as the user types. However, changing the height of ion-textarea itself doesn't work. The code in my directive that changes the height:

```
 adjust(): void {
      console.log(this.element.nativeElement);
        let nativeElement = this.element.nativeElement;
        nativeElement.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        nativeElement.style.height = 'auto';
        nativeElement.style.height = nativeElement.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
```

I suspect that the height doesn't change, because the this.element.nativeElement is ion-textarea (instead of textarea). How can I access the native textarea to alter its height?

Here is a **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cxzda3?file=directives%2Fauto-resize.directive.ts)** that shows the problem. The directive is the auto-resize directive, and the page with the ion-textarea is the home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the native textarea can be accesed in the host listener of the directive:

```
@HostListener('input', ['$event.target'])
onInput(textArea: HTMLTextAreaElement): void {
    this.adjust(textArea);
}
```

after this the textarea can be manipulated in the adjust() function.